# How to use an observable within `filter`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs6

Suppose I have a directory structure similar to following:

```
foo
|
+---one
|   +---tmp
|
+---two
|
+---three
    |
    +---tmp
```

I want to get the list of sub-directories under `foo` which has a `tmp` (sub-)sub-directory underneath. I do have the following code which does that:

```
const { bindNodeCallback, from } = require('rxjs');
const { map, flatMap, filter } = require('rxjs/operators');
const { readdir, access, accessSync, constants: { F_OK, R_OK }} = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

const readdirRx = bindNodeCallback(readdir);

const FOO = './foo';

const result = readdirRx(FOO)
    .pipe(
        // readdir will return an array of files. Convert each
        // file into an observable, and then flatten it.
        flatMap(from),

        // get rid of directories that do not have a `tmp` dir underneath
        filter(dir => {
            try {
                accessSync(join(FOO, dir, 'tmp'), F_OK | R_OK);
                return true;
            } catch (err) {
                return false;
            }
        })
    );
result.subscribe(console.log, console.error, () => console.log('Done!'));
// outputs (correctly):
//   one
//   three
//   Done!
```

However, this code looks awful to me because (a) I am using exceptions for control flow, and (b) there is a synchronous `accessSync` call, both of which are detrimental to performance.

I do have the following reactive piece of code that checks the same thing:

```
const fileExistsAndReadableRx = bindNodeCallback(
    // check if file exists and readable
    (file, cb) => access(file, F_OK | R_OK,
        // call the callback with true if no errors found
        err => cb(!err)
    )
);
```

However, I cannot figure out how I can plug `fileExistsAndReadableRx` into the above program. My objective is to remove the try-catch block and use `fileExistsAndReadableRx` instead to filter out sub-directories that do not have a `tmp` (sub-)sub-directory. How can I do that?

(Please note that the actual task I am trying to do is not reading the disk. What I am trying to do is a complex async operation, and I had to come up with a simpler example to illustrate my problem).

#### What I have tried so far:

I tried to use `map`, but it emits a stream of Observables, as one would expect:

```
const result = readdirRx(FOO)
    .pipe(
        flatMap(from),
        map(dir =>
            fileExistsAndReadableRx(join(FOO, dir, 'tmp'))
        )
    );
result.subscribe(console.log, console.error, () => console.log('Done!'));
// Outputs:
//   Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }
//   Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }
//   Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }
//   Done!
```

So I thought, *I know! I'd use `flatMap` to flatten the Observables. That should produce three boolean values that are eventually emitted from those Observables*. But that did not work either. It only emits a single value:

```
const result = readdirRx(FOO)
    .pipe(
        flatMap(from),
        flatMap(dir =>
            fileExistsAndReadableRx(join(FOO, dir, 'tmp'))
        )
    );
result.subscribe(console.log, console.error, () => console.log('Done!'));
// Outputs:
//   true
//   Done!
```

#### Edit:

I tried [@IngoBurk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1675492/ingo-b%C3%BCrk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51348234/1461424), but that produces a single boolean value. Not a list of strings as I would expect:

```
const result = readdirRx(FOO)
    .pipe(
        flatMap(from),
        flatMap(dir => fileExistsAndReadableRx(join(FOO, dir, 'tmp'))
            .pipe(
                filter(Boolean),
                map(() => dir),
            )
        ),
    );
result.subscribe(console.log, console.error, () => console.log('Done!'));
// Outputs:
//   true
//   Done!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
readdirRx(FOO)
  .pipe(
    flatMap(from),
    flatMap(dir => fileExistsAndReadableRx(join(FOO, dir, 'tmp'))
      .pipe(
        catchError(res => of(res)),
        filter(Boolean),
        map(() => dir),
      )
    ),
  )
```

It assumes that `fileExistsAndReadableRx` returns `Observable<boolean>`. `filter(Boolean)` is just short for `filter(v => !!v)`.

The trick here is essentially what you tried, which is (flat-)mapping each directory to the observable checking for the tmp folder. We then use that result to filter out those not matching it and then map it back to the directory rather than that intermediate result.

You can see it in action here: https://rxviz.com/v/d8djbkRO

> you'd probably want to use `cb(null, !err)` to invoke the callback in `fileExistsAndReadableRx`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this produces a single boolean value as the result. (Please see my edit). Oh, and +1 for rxviz.

Comment: @Krumia The problem is that `fileExistsAndReadableRx` doesn't emit true/false, but instead *errors* with those values. I've slightly updated my answer with a bit of a hack; you might want to solve this a bit nicer.

Comment: I'm no longer at a computer right now, but instead of catchError as in my edit you'd probably want to use `cb(null, !err)` to invoke the callback in `fileExistsAndReadableRx`

Comment: Damn I'm such an idiot. That's it, it's `cb(null, !err)`, and not `cb(!err)`. I hope you don't mind me adding your comment to answer so I can accept it.